# SQL server job agent fails to execute SSIS package, the package runs fine manually

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssis, visual-studio

I have a job which executes two packages. Step 1 is a package which is no longer executing under the job agent although it was executing fine before the server reboot. The package executes fine manually but under the job agent it has the following:

[image]

SOME facts:

1. The job uses a proxy account to call the packages
2. The account password was changed recently but the jobs did run fine after the change was made
3. There was a server reboot and the failures started straight after

Interestingly, the second step, which is a package with almost similar access to the databases and exact same proxy account does run successfully within the job agent.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

- change to 32 bit
- change creator name
- checked that the proxy still has access to the database ( it does because the second package does)
- Error logs- these do not appear as the actual termination does is not flagged as an error.
- The termination seems to occur at the execute phase of the dataflow, which is executing a procedure in the database.  So I have checked all the parameters and variables effecting the dataflow task to no avail.

I have seen a similar post to this, however the other post is an error message rather than a termination.

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATED the messages from the query suggested by @billinkc
[image]

Comment: I don't see an actual error message in this. You have Warning, Informational and PostValidation messages but there should be something to correlate with the status of Unexpected Termination. If you query the SSISDB for the operation, let's get the details `SELECT OM.message_type, OM.message_source_type, OM.message FROM ssisdb.catalog.operation_messages AS OM WHERE OM.operation_id = 19920;` (value in the top left)

Comment: @billinkc That is the strange thing. I have updated the question with the result from the query you suggested, 21 messages in total.